# Heroku postgres connection failed because of password auth

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, heroku-postgres

I want to connect to the heroku postgres database I have set up using spring boot java. But before that I wanted to try and connect using pgAdmin 4. When I tried this I got an error saying the authentication for the 'username' had failed.
Then I started adding the database to my application.proporties file in spring boot to test it there. I got the samen error message.
This is the error message I got in spring boot: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username".
I then even tried it in DBeaver. But still the same error.

[heroku postgres credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S00gk.jpg)

[application.properties in spring boot java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Lh7.jpg)

I checked multiple times if the password and username are the same. I really don't know what to do now, because I can't find any documantation on the heroku website

Comment: "I checked multiple times if the password and username are the same."  The same as what?

Comment: Is there any tool/location from which you can connect?  If so, please describe it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm NO EXPERT but I did have the same problem.  I think I fixed it on the page with fields for Host, Port, Maintenance database, Username, Password, ... and then by toggling "save password."

Comment: For some reason, Heroku no longer updated `DATABASE_URL` automatically. I had to go to the Settings page, Reveal Config Vars, and then manually copy from the new env variable `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL` into the more env variable name used by my code. Is Heroku degrading?

Comment: Heroku sent this email: "Your database... on ... requires maintenance. During this period, your database will become read-only. Once maintenance has completed, your database credentials and hostname will have changed, but we will update your app's config variables accordingly to reflect the new database connection string."   I had to manually reconfigure mine too.